# Magento Configurable Products Do Not Show Up

Tags: magento, categories, configurable-product

My configurable products do not show up.  Here is how I set up The configurable product:

1) Created two attributes that are global, dropdown with 
"Apply to Configurable Product" and "Use to Create Configurable Product"="Yes".

2) Added these two attributes to an attribute set.

3) Create a new configurable product based on this attribute set.

4) Select both attributes in my attribute set.

5) Add a default price to the configurable attribute, and set manage stock to "No".

6) Under Associated Product:  I filled out all fields with visibility = "Not Visible Individually" and "Stock"="in stock".

7) I am also using the "Parent Product Thumbnail" for each associated product.

At this point, I am expecting:

1)  As each associated products is created, it appears in the list at the bottom of the admin page.  There should be one associated product at the bottom of the page, but there is not.

2)  In the front end, I am expecting my configurable product to show up but I cannot see it in the navigational filters.  I am expecting that the navigational filters reflect information for the associated products.

3)  I am expecting that the product listing and the product page shows options for product variation along with images from the parent product.  However I cannot get anything to show up.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to choose the attribute in simple product which are used as super attribute configurable product.
For example an super attribute "color" is used for configurable product and in the simple product you have not choose any "color" attribute.

After that in configurable product, associate the same simple product.